# What does "fresh module namespace" mean w.r.t. runpy?

Tags: python, runpy

http://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module

My question is about this part of the run_module documentation.

> ... and then executed in a fresh module namespace.

What is a "module namespace" in python? In what ways does runpy differ from **import**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every module executes with its own set of global variables, which become the module's attributes. A module namespace is where a module's globals go; "executed in a fresh module namespace" means "executed with its own global variable environment".

A Python interpreter only executes a module's code the first time it's imported in any given program. Further import statements simply return the existing module object. This prevents exponential import explosion when modules `a` and `b` both import modules `c` and `d`, which both import `e` and `f`, etc. It also means that all modules see the same versions of, say, `collections.defaultdict`, so type checks behave intuitively. `runpy.run_module` says "run the code in this module, whether or not it was imported already, and don't count it as an import." If you `run_module` a module and then `__import__` it, the dict you got from `run_module` will contain objects very similar to, but distinct from, the objects in the module you got from `__import__`.